# How are unit maintenance costs and supply related?

Tags: civilization-5

Early in this one game i had 5 military units and 3 workers. My unit maintenance was 11g per turn. So i thought 1g per military and 2g per civilian unit. Then i saw this bit about supply in the military overview. What does that mean and how does it affect unit maintenance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The supply limit based on your empire size is not related to the upkeep cost. Instead, if you exceed the supply limit, all your cities take a 10% production penalty. In most games, you will run out of money before you get to that point.

Comment: Ok, so my initial guess (1g for military, 2g for civilan) was correct and nothing else influences unit upkeep cost?

Comment: @Bubblewrap: The Autocracy social policy gives you a 33% discount on unit maintenance. Also, I am not sure whether those numbers are correct. In my current game, I have 3 military units and 2 civilian, and am paying 3 gold/turn upkeep. Maybe it's 1 per unit for the first x and then goes up to 2? Or maybe there are more rules involved, like first unit of each type is free, or maintenance costs only update with each pair of units? I haven't done extensive testing.

Comment: I see, thanks anyway, i guess my main question is answered. "They aren't." :)

Comment: Okay, so now I'm pretty sure that maintenance costs only increase with every other unit and I haven't been able to figure out a difference between military or civilian units. Marginal costs do increase as you get more units, but it seems like it also depends on other factors...

Answer (score 1):

Workers cost 9-11 gold for a pair. If you liberate (delete) one, you get no benefit. Liberate the second, and you'll get the 9-11Gold reduced from your maintenance costs.

Military seems to work the same, but I'm sure that it's not every pair. Riflemen come in a quartet (retire 3, no benefit. Retire the 4th, 9-11 gold).

I wasn't watching too closely, but I believe Barbarian Brutes cost 6G each (they may have been paired, I can't remember...).

Also, I don't know if death during combat counts towards the unit maintenance reduction.